# How to change color of UITextView by clicking on the button using swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uitextview

I have a UITextView, which should have two different colours. At first it should be in default colour, for example black. And when I press button to turn to another mode (incognito) it should change colour of text to the white colour. Here is my code:

```
   func textViewStartEd(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray || textView.textColor == UIColor.white {
    textView.text = nil
    textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

[image: In standard should be black]
[image: In another mode should be white]

Answer (score 2):

-> Create a global variable

```
private var toggle: Bool = false
```

-> create a button click event and call a toggle variable logic and ToggleIncongneto Function

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    toggle = !toggle // Toggle logic 
    ToggleIncongneto(on: toggle) // toggle func
}
```

-> Create function to toggle the View

```
func ToggleIncongneto(on: Bool) {
    txtfld.backgroundColor = on ? .black : .systemGray6 // change background color
    txtfld.textColor = on ? .white : .black // change text color
}
```

[image]

Comment: It should change colour of text view only, this don't helped me

Comment: I've just change something in you code and it works, thank you

Comment: you can change any view on button click by this method

Comment: can you pls make it a right.. as it is working fine